# ARMA process with correlated input noise - how to determine the autocovariance function of the output

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation

Starting from the IMA form of an ARMA model, Karanasos' (2007) [paper in the discontinued QASS Journal](http://www.mkaranasos.com/QASS07.pdf) derived the autocovariance function of an ARMA process in terms of the AR and MA parameters and the variance of the input sequence, roughly as follows.

Starting from the IMA form of an ARMA process:

\begin{equation}
y_t = \mu + \sum_{\tau=0}^\infty e_{\tau}\epsilon_{t-\tau} \quad \mbox{with} \quad e_{\tau} = \sum_{l=1}^p \sum_{\kappa=0}^{\mathrm{min}\left(\tau,\,q\right)} \zeta_{l,\, \tau-\kappa} \theta_{\kappa} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \zeta_{l,\, \tau-\kappa} = \frac{\phi_l^{p-1+\tau-\kappa}}{\prod_{r=1,\, r\neq l}^p\left(\phi_l-\phi_r\right)}
\end{equation}

he suggested that the autocovariance function of the resulting process, driven by the i.i.d. input sequence $\epsilon_t$ could be determined by multiplying $(y_t-\mu)$ by $(y_{t-m}-u)$ and taking expectations which would give:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Cov}\left[y_t\right] = \sum_{\tau=0}^\infty e_{\tau}e_{\tau+m}\sigma^2.
\end{equation}

However, if the assumption of an i.i.d. input were relaxed, then how would this change? I assume this latter expression for the covariance of $y_t$ would also include the covariance structure of the input rather than just the variance - but I can't quite see how to show that.